# Mouse Position changes when clicking / pressing keys?

Tags: c++, c++11, keyboard, mouse, sfml

So, I'm currently developing my first game (and C++ application) as a hobby, but I've run into a problem and I'm not sure how to get around it. Any help is of course appreciated.

My problem is as follows:

Whenever I click, or press a key on the keyboard, the mouse coordinates jump to really strange values, and then return to normal a second later. This messes up my vector calculations for bullet trajectories, etc.

Example: http://puu.sh/3xjFq.jpg

As you can see in my console window, the Y coordinate jumps from the correct value (628) to (-858993460), then to (65536), then to the correct value again.

Code I am using to retrieve the mouse coordinates:

```
cout << "X: " << event.mouseMove.x << " Y: " << event.mouseMove.y << endl;
```

This is also the same code I am using to retrieve mouse coordinates for calculations.

I'm guessing the source of my problem is SFML itself, and the way it works. What would be an alternative for retrieving mouse coordinates?

Note that I'm still very very new at this (started last week) so try to keep everything as simple as possible.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: That's code to print the mouse coordinates. Where's all the code to retrieve the coordinates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Events are stored in an union in SFML. If you don't know how unions work, you should definitely read about it ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type#C.2FC.2B.2B)). In one word, different variables share the same space in memory. This obviously gives you strange values when interpreting them with the wrong type.

When you write :

```
event.mouseMove.x/y
```

the value of the members `x` or `y` are only valid if the event you're looking at is an `sf::Event::MouseMoved`. If you want to check the coordinates of the mouse when a button is pressed (that is, an event of type `sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed`) you must use

```
event.mouseButton.x/y
```

Comment: event.mouseButton.x and event.mouseButton.y isn't valid SFML code though.

Comment: @user2558804 It is, check this tutorial : http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/window-events.php

Comment: Ah, I think I understand it now. But what do I do about Key Presses? Isn't there another way of getting mouse position without resorting to the union method that SFML uses?

Comment: @user2558804 The classic way is to have a switch to distingate the type of event, as in the tutorial (first code sample). You can also get the actual state of the mouse like this ( http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/window-inputs.php#mouse ). IMHO you should read those 2 tutorials as they are very basics that need to be well understood.